# What's the point of `use vars` in this Perl subroutine?

Tags: perl

In one of the chapters in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242), brian d foy shows this snippet from [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html):

```
sub reduce(&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    no strict "refs";
    return shift unless @_ > 1;
    use vars qw($a $b);
    my $caller = caller;
    local(*{$caller . "::a"}) = \my $a;
    local(*{$caller . "::b"}) = \my $b;
    $a = shift;
    foreach(@_) {
        $b = $_;
        $a = &{$code}();
    }
    $a;
}
```

I don't understand what's the point of the `use vars qw($a $b)` line. Even if I comment it, I get the same output & warnings.

Comment: Did you use `use strict; use warnings;` before all that?

Comment: One quibble - the code listed is not Bryan D Foy's - he is quoting the code from Graham Barr (creator of List::Util)

Comment: `strict` and `warnings` tends to illuminate errors that would otherwise remain un-illuminated; basically, it's the first go-to problem solver for Perl related issues.

Comment: If you read the part right after that code snippet, I show you why you don't need most of that code. It's an example of how not to do it. :)

Comment: @DVK: that code isn't brian d foy's, either. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is done because List::Util uses reduce() function internally.

In the abscence of `use vars`, the following warning is given when the function is used:

```
Name "List::MyUtil::a" used only once: possible typo at a.pl line 35.
Name "List::MyUtil::b" used only once: possible typo at a.pl line 35.
```

You can see this for yourself by running the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package List::MyUtil;

sub reduce (&@) {
   # INSERT THE TEXT FROM SUBROUTINE HERE - deleted to save space in the answer
}

sub x {
    return reduce(sub {$a+$b}, 1,2,3);
}

package main;
my $res = List::MyUtil::x();
print "$res\n";
```

And then running it again with `use vars` disabled.

Comment: The fact that the package uses reduce makes sense now. Without that explanation, I didn't know what to believe.

Comment: One more question, if I may. What's the point of the lexical $a and $b? Why didn't he reference the global ones?

Comment: The tip-off for the correct answer lies in the fact that use vars only applies to the current package. Thus it'd be of no use to anyone by List::Utils itself.

Comment: As for referencing the global ones, I assume same reason nobody should use global variables - you don't want to step on some other piece of code's feet.

Answer (score 2):

As DVK notes, if we run the code with the `use vars` commented out, we will get a warning about variables being used only once.

Another way to suppress the warning is on the caller side -- that is, in the call to `reduce` rather than within the `reduce` function. One has to do this when using functions from `List::Util` or `List::MoreUtils` that take code references (for example, `pairwise`). Both of these approaches work on the caller side:

```
my @sums = pairwise { no warnings 'once'; $a + $b } @x, @y;

my @sums = pairwise { our($a, $b);        $a + $b } @x, @y;
```

Comment: Correct - but if reduce() is in fact used many times in List::Utils, doing this only once inside reduce() is a better approach for the module writer, though it doesn't help people using the module of course :)

Answer (score 0):

From the paragraph right after that code explains it. There's a mix of package and lexical variables in the same scope:

> The rest of reduce works like sort by putting two elements into the package variables $a and $b. Graham defines the lexical variables with those names, and immediately assigns to the typeglobs for $a and $b in the calling package by using symbolic references. After that the values of $a and $b are the lexical versions. When he calls the subroutine argument &{$code}(), that code looks at its package variables, which are the ones in effect when I wrote the subroutine. Got that? Inside reduce, I'm using the lexical versions, but inside $code, I'm using the package versions from the calling package. That's why Graham made them aliases of each other.