# Why is this statement treated as a string instead of its result?

Tags: regex, perl, string

I am trying to perform some composition-based filtering on a large collection of strings (protein sequences).
I wrote a group of three subroutines in order to take care of it, but I'm running into trouble in two ways - one minor, one major.  The minor trouble is that when I use [List::MoreUtils 'pairwise'](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils#pairwise) I get warnings about using `$a` and `$b` only once and them being uninitialized.  But I believe I'm calling this method properly (based on CPAN's entry for it and some examples from the web).
The major trouble is an error `"Can't use string ("17/32") as HASH ref while "strict refs" in use..."`

It seems like this can only happen if the `foreach` loop in `&comp` is giving the hash values as a string instead of evaluating the division operation.  I'm sure I've made a rookie mistake, but can't find the answer on the web.  The first time I even looked at perl code was last Wednesday...

```
use List::Util;
use List::MoreUtils;
my @alphabet = (
 'A', 'R', 'N', 'D', 'C', 'Q', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I',
 'L', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'Y', 'V'
);
my $gapchr = '-';
# Takes a sequence and returns letter => occurrence count pairs as hash.
sub getcounts {
 my %counts = ();
 foreach my $chr (@alphabet) {
  $counts{$chr} = ( $_[0] =~ tr/$chr/$chr/ );
 }
 $counts{'gap'} = ( $_[0] =~ tr/$gapchr/$gapchr/ );
 return %counts;
}

# Takes a sequence and returns letter => fractional composition pairs as a hash.
sub comp {
 my %comp = getcounts( $_[0] );
 foreach my $chr (@alphabet) {
  $comp{$chr} = $comp{$chr} / ( length( $_[0] ) - $comp{'gap'} );
 }
 return %comp;
}

# Takes two sequences and returns a measure of the composition difference between them, as a scalar.
# Originally all on one line but it was unreadable.

sub dcomp {
 my @dcomp = pairwise { $a - $b } @{ values( %{ comp( $_[0] ) } ) }, @{ values( %{ comp( $_[1] ) } ) };
 @dcomp = apply { $_ ** 2 } @dcomp;
 my $dcomp = sqrt( sum( 0, @dcomp ) ) / 20;
 return $dcomp;
}
```

Much appreciation for any answers or advice!

Comment: Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261871/whats-the-point-of-use-vars-in-this-perl-subroutine/2261957#2261957 for more explanation of why/how this stuff happens. +1

Comment: Which line is that hash ref error on?

Comment: For the minor problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490505/how-do-i-prevent-listmoreutils-from-warning-about-using-a-and-b-only-once.

Comment: Hash ref error is in &comp at $comp{$chr} = $comp{$chr} / ( length( $_[0] ) - $comp{'gap'} )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%{ $foo }` will treat `$foo` as a hash reference and dereference it; similarly, `@{}` will dereference array references. Since `comp` returns a hash as a list (hashes becomes lists when passed to and from functions) and not a hash reference, the `%{}` is wrong. You could potentially leave off the `%{}`, but `values` is a special form and needs a hash, not a hash passed as a list. To pass the result of `comp` to `values`, `comp` needs to return a hash ref that then gets dereferenced.

There's another problem with your `dcomp`, namely that the order of `values` (as the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) says) "are returned in an apparently random order", so the values passed to the `pairwise` block aren't necessarily for the same character. Instead of `values`, you can use hash slices. We're now back to `comp` returning a hash (as a list).

```
sub dcomp {
    my %ahisto = comp($_[0]);
    my %bhisto = comp($_[1]);
    my @keys = uniq keys %ahisto, keys %bhisto;
    my @dcomp = pairwise { $a - $b } , @ahisto{@keys}, @bhisto{@keys};
    @dcomp = apply { $_ ** 2 } @dcomp;
    my $dcomp = sqrt( sum( 0, @dcomp ) ) / 20;
    return $dcomp;
}
```

This doesn't address what happens if a character appears in only one of `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`.

`uniq` left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I think the hash slices have to be enclosed by @{ [ ] }?
Now I know about the danger of values(), thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few bugs in your code. First, note from [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> Because the transliteration table is built at compile time, **neither the `SEARCHLIST` nor the `REPLACEMENTLIST` are subjected to double quote interpolation**.

So your counting method is incorrect. I also believe you are misusing `pairwise`. It is hard to evaluate what constitutes correct usage because you do not give examples of what output you should get with some simple inputs.

In any case, I would re-write this script as (there are some debugging statements sprinkled in):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use List::AllUtils qw( sum );
use YAML;

our ($a, $b);
my @alphabet = ('A' .. 'Z');
my $gap = '-';

my $seq1 = 'ABCD-EFGH--MNOP';
my $seq2 = 'EFGH-ZZZH-KLMN';

print composition_difference($seq1, $seq2);

sub getcounts {
    my ($seq) = @_;
    my %counts;
    my $pattern = join '|', @alphabet, $gap;
    $counts{$1} ++ while $seq =~ /($pattern)/g;
    warn Dump \%counts;
    return \%counts;
}

sub fractional_composition_pairs {
    my ($seq) = @_;
    my $comp = getcounts( $seq );
    my $denom = length $seq - $comp->{$gap};
    $comp->{$_} /= $denom for @alphabet;
    warn Dump $comp;
    return $comp;
}

sub composition_difference {
    # I think your use of pairwise in the original script
    # is very buggy unless every sequence always contains
    # all the letters in the alphabet and the gap character.
    # Is the gap character supposed to factor in the computations here?

    my ($comp1, $comp2) = map { fractional_composition_pairs($_) } @_;
    my %union;
    ++ $union{$_} for (keys %$comp1, keys %$comp2);

    my $dcomp;
    {
        no warnings 'uninitialized';
        $dcomp = sum map {
            ($comp1->{$_} - $comp2->{$_}) ** 2
        } keys %union;
    }

    return sqrt( $dcomp ) / 20; # where did 20 come from?
}
```

Comment: Without going into the biology (doesn't seem like the place!), the sequence gaps don't constitute differences in the "composition" of the sequences, because they aren't a letter in the alphabet (of the 20 amino acids).  The 20 is to (arbitrarily) normalize $dcomp from 0 to 1.  

I get map() now...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just going through the code that you provided, this is how I would have written it. I don't know if this will work the way you wanted it to work though.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
our( $a, $b );

use List::Util;
use List::MoreUtils;

my @alphabet = split '', 'ARNDCQEGHILKMFPSTWYV';
my $gapchr = '-';
# Takes a sequence and returns letter => occurrence count pairs as hash.
sub getcounts {
  my( $sequence ) = @_;
  my %counts;
  for my $chr (@alphabet) {
    $counts{$chr} = () = $sequence =~ /($chr)/g;
    # () = forces list context
  }
  $counts{'gap'} = () = $sequence =~ /($gapchr)/g;
  return %counts if wantarray; # list context
  return \%counts; # scalar context
  # which is what happens inside of %{  }
}

# Takes a sequence and returns letter => fractional composition pairs as a hash
sub comp {
  my( $sequence ) = @_;
  my %counts = getcounts( $sequence );
  my %comp;
  for my $chr (@alphabet) {
    $comp{$chr} = $comp{$chr} / ( length( $sequence ) - $counts{'gap'} );
  }
  return %comp if wantarray; # list context
  return \%comp; # scalar context
}

# Takes two sequences and returns a measure of the composition difference
#   between them, as a scalar.
sub dcomp {
  my( $seq1, $seq2 ) = @_;
  my @dcomp = pairwise { $a - $b }
    @{[ values( %{ comp( $seq1 ) } ) ]},
    @{[ values( %{ comp( $seq2 ) } ) ]};
  # @{[ ]} makes a list into an array reference, then dereferences it.
  # values always returns a list
  # a list, or array in scalar context, returns the number of elements
  # ${  } @{  } and %{  } forces their contents into scalar context

  @dcomp = apply { $_ ** 2 } @dcomp;
  my $dcomp = sqrt( sum( 0, @dcomp ) ) / 20;
  return $dcomp;
}
```

One of the most important things you need to know are the differences between scalar, list, and void contexts. This is because **everything** behaves different, in the different contexts.

Comment: Ah, yes I see about the contexts.  'if wantarray' is a neat trick.

Answer (score 1):

**re: Minor problem**

This is fine and a common problem with (some) of the `List::Util` and `List::MoreUtils` modules.

One way to remove warnings is simply to declare those `special variables` in advance like so:

```
our ($a, $b);
```

Another would be to precede the `pairwise` with:

```
no warnings 'once';
```

See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for more info about $a and $b

/I3az/

Comment: Would you make that declaration in the sub block or in the, uh, global namespace (I'm not so good on the correct terms)?
Seems to me like the former if I use the method once and the latter if I use it in many places?

Comment: Putting `our ($a, $b)` at top of program is fine in this instance.   $a & $b are special and so *shouldn't* be used for anything else bar sort & modules like List::Util.   The issue is that `warnings once` isn't taking $a & $b special variables into account except for `sort`